# How to refer to a single value in a Calculated Column in a measure (DAX)

Tags: calculated-columns, powerpivot, dax, measure

I have a table(Data_all) that calculates daycount_ytd in one table.

```
[Date] is in Date Format. 
[Fiscal Year] is just year. eg: 2016

Calculated Column
daycount_ytd=DATEDIFF("01/01/"&[Fiscal Year],Data_all[Date],day)+1
```

Im trying to create a measure that refers to this Calculated Column

```
Measure:
Amt_X Yield %:=[Amt X]/([Amt Y]/365* (Data_all[DayCount_YTD]))
```

I get the error that Data_all[DayCount_YTD] refers to a list of values. 
How do i filter the expression to get a single value without using a aggregation function eg:(sum, median)?

Or perhaps, is there another way to achieve the same calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You've arrived an a fundamental concept in DAX and once you've worked out how to deal with it then the solution generalises to loads of scenarios.

Basically you can't just pass columns into a DAX measure without wrapping them in something else - generally some kind of mathematical operation or you can use VALUES() depending on exactly what you are trying to do.

This measure will work OK if you use it in a PIVOT with the date as a row label:

```
=
  SUM ( data_all[Amt X] )
   / (
      SUM ( data_all[Amt Y] ) / 365
      * MAX ( data_all[daycount_ytd] )
      )
```

However you will see it gives you an incorrect total as it is in the latest for the entire thing. What you need is a version that iterates over the rows and then performs a calculation to SUM or AVERAGE each item. There is a whole class of DAX functions dedicated to this such as SUMX, AVERAGEX etc. You can read more about them [here](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2010/02/sumx-the-5-point-palm-exploding-fxn-technique/)

It's not totally clear to me what the maths behind your 'total' should be but the following measure calculates the value for each day and sums them together:

```
=
  SUMX(
      VALUES(data_all[date]), 
         SUM(data_all[Amt X]) / 
         (SUM(data_all[Amt Y]) / 365 * MAX(data_all[daycount_ytd]))
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the formula is actually for a percentage calculation, so i dont think i can sum the value for each day.

Comment: I used values() combined with another table(single row) to get to my calculation in the end.